# PHP: setting a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

trying to save the username as a cookie when the user is logged into the website.

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblmember WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $cookie_name = "user";
        $cookie_value = $results;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      //set username as a cookie & then use that to access the user pages.
        echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
      header('location: profile.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
    }
  }
}
```

I tried testing this and it worked first time with: $cookie_value = "lol"; then I switched it to $cookie_value = $results; saved the changes and deleted that cookie from google chrome. I then tried to re-open the page in chrome again to find that the cookie wasn't being set at all.

Comment: Repost of [How do I fix this? The cookie isn't setting](//stackoverflow.com/q/56031459)

Comment: @mario yeah, I noticed that too (having closed the last one). However this is actually a different problem (note that the commentary says setting a cookie worked with a literal string, but not with the `$results` variable).

Comment: Please be aware that you're vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this. In addition to this, `md5()` is [**highly insecure**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) (even with a salt) and should **NOT** be used for password storage. Instead, you should consider [**`password_hash()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [**`password_verify()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `setcookie` must be a string. You are passing it a `mysqli::result` object. You need to fetch the results from the query and then use something like [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to convert the result to a string which you can then store into a cookie. For example:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = serialize($row);
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
    // ...
```